create user in aem with user manager api from java application
I want to create a user in aem with user manager api from Java application. I have used the below code for connectivity aem.
Repository myRepo = JcrUtils.getRepository(path);
javax.jcr.Session repoSession = myRepo.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray())); 

But there is method i.e "getUserManager" in JackrabbitSession interface which does not invoked with session.
JackrabbitSession is child interface of session.
then how to call method with jcr.session so that we can create user in aem
i want to create user in aem with java application.

Did you find how to do it?

No, I am changing my approach
